# How to find integrals of the form $\int_{-r}^{+r}\frac{\gamma^{2}-1-y^{2}}{y-z\gamma} dy$

Tags: complex-integration

I'm trying to solve the above integral which will give a dispersion relation. 
Note: $\gamma$ and y are real but z is a complex variable.

Comment: Is it also safe to assume that $r$ is real and positive?

Comment: Yes it is. $$r=\sqrt{\gamma^{2}-1}$$ and $$\gamma^{2}>1$$.